# Graph API to know when email is sent

Tags: c#, api, .net-6.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently sending emails via Graph API using the following code:

```
var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient();
var metadata = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyMetadata>(queueItem);

if (metadata is null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not convert metadata");
                
await graphClient.Users[metadata.MailboxUsername].Messages[metadata.OutlookPlugInIdentityGUID].Send().Request().PostAsync();
```

Whilst this works, I have no way of knowing when the email has actually sent. The code that I have considered to check is a **while** loop like this:

```
while (isSent == false)
{
    var checkMessage = await graphClient.Users[metadata.MailboxUsername].Messages[metadata.OutlookPlugInIdentityGUID].Request().GetAsync();

    if (checkMessage.IsDraft == false)
    {
        isSent = true;
    }
    else if (noOfAttempts > 50) { throw new Exception("some error message"); }
    
    noOfAttempts += 1;
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

This is obviously very inefficient and runs the risk of causing Graph to throttle API calls which would potentially cause a performance bottleneck. Is there a cleaner and more efficient way of determining when an email has been successfully sent?

I need to know when the email has been sent so that I can trigger a separate process in sequence.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can send HTTP request and check the status code of the response.

Example:

```
var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient();
var metadata = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyMetadata>(queueItem);

if (metadata is null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not convert metadata");
            
var requestUrl = graphClient.Users[metadata.MailboxUsername].Messages[metadata.OutlookPlugInIdentityGUID].Send().Request().RequestUrl;

// Create the request message and add the content.
var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);

// Authenticate (add access token) our HttpRequestMessage
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

// Send the request and get the response.
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    ...
}
else
    throw new ServiceException(
        new Error
        {
            Code = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
            Message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        });
```

Resources:

[Send HTTP request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#send-http-requests-with-the-net-microsoft-graph-client-library)

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, this doesn't really resolve the issue that I am facing. The responses that I am receiving aren't the issue, it's the 'IsDraft' status that is essentially causing problems. There is a lag between the Outlook client application 'synchronising' a draft email to the server, and the Graph API being able to retrieve an up-to-date version of that email. The default delay is 3 minutes for an email to get saved to the drafts box. When that happens, the email that I retrieve only contains the email content up to the 3 minute mark (unless I loop and check the draft flag)

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would put an answer up for anyone who is facing the same issue. Essentially there is no 'clean' workaround but what I ended up doing was calling the saveAsync function on my client side application to *forcefully* tell Exchange to update the information it holds about my mail message. Instead of then waiting on a response from my API, I decided to pass control back to the user and run an exponential backoff retry policy in an Azure function. This allows me to 'wait' for the send to actually occur but without having a loading spinner stuck on the users screen for a long time.

A substantial drawback to this approach that I should mention however, is that the user can delete the email before it is actually sent, and that prevents you from acquiring an immutable identifier at a later time if you need to be able to run update operations or find the email later on (for example I set a category on the email object and that's not possible if the email gets deleted first).